# Conditional Probability Question for a give population

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

Suppose that in a given population, 30% are senior citizens. Of those that are
senior citizens, 80% like the Bee Gees. Only 5% of those who are not senior citizens actually like the Bee Gees.

(a) What is the probability of a person being a senior citizen, given that he/she likes the Bee Gees?.

Currently I have this solved as 24/29. If 29% of the population like the Bee Gees and 24% of the total population are seniors, then its 24/29. Not sure if I'm not understanding something as it doesn't seem quite right.

(b) What is the probability of a person not being a senior citizen, given that he/she does not like the Bee
Gees?

I did the opposite here and choose 79% as not liking the Bee Gees, then 70% for non seniors.

Now for both of these I understand I could use the conditional probability (P(B|A)) formula, but I'm not sure how to find the overlap in each for the 
P(A AND B) part.

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this using bayes' theorem.

```
P(SeniorCitizen) = 0.3
P(NotSeniorCitizen) = 0.7
P(BeeGees | SeniorCitizen) = 0.8
P(BeeGees | NotSeniorCitizen) = 0.05
P(NotBeeGees | NotSeniorCitizen) = 0.95
```

(a)  probability of a person being a senior citizen, given that he/she likes the Bee Gees is given as below:

```
P(SeniorCitizen | BeeGees) = (0.8*0.3) / (0.05*0.7 + 0.8*0.3)
                           = 0.872
```

(b) probability of a person not being a senior citizen, given that he/she does not like the Bee Gees is given as below:

```
P(NotSeniorCitizen | NotBeeGees) = (0.95*0.7) / (0.2*0.3 + 0.95*0.7)
                                 = 0.917
```